# Angular : sanitizing HTML stripped some content on css style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using a wysiwyg editor in my Angular component, when i try to preview the content of the editor, (after i apply center to the text),
i get this warning:

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
> platform-browser.es5.js:1015

when i inspect the html:

```
<p>Text Here...</p>
```

but when i try to use console.log() to preview the content of the editor i get:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Text Here...</p>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is by design in Angular 2+ for security reasons. You can workaround it by using the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/core/Sanitizer) class.

For example you can make a pipe that prevents sanitization of the value:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'noSanitize' })
export class NoSanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

   }
   transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
   }
}
```

Then you can use it in binding for example like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlText | noSanitize">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to strip content of dangerous things while keeping the style attributes?

Comment: can anyone put this on npm?