# Angular: how to avoid stripping innerHtml?

Tags: angular

I want to show `@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart`, emoji's in a chat component. But I have to set data using `innerHtml` as in following.

```
<div [innerHtml]="message"></div>
message = "<ngx-emoji [emoji]="{ id: 'santa', skin: 3 }" size="16"></ngx-emoji>"
```

So as mentioned in here, [Angular 2: sanitizing HTML stripped some content on css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681813/angular-2-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-on-css-style/47682389). I used following `pipe`,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'noSanitize' })
export class NoSanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

   }
   transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
   }
}
```

Now angular doesn't stripping messages like `<h2>Hello</h2>`, but if message contain ngx-emoji  tags, angular still stripping. So how can I prevent this and show emoji tags in chat messages?

Comment: Why not put the `<ngx-emoji>` directly in the HTML!

`<div><ngx-emoji [emoji]="{ id: 'santa', skin: 3 }" size="16"></ngx-emoji></div>`

Comment: You need to load the component dynamically, have a look there: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader